# Reverse Engineering Flash

Tags: flash, reverse-engineering

I have some Flash SWF files that I need some insight into how they are working.  Are they any good tools out there to reverse engineer a SWF file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Disassemble the SWF with [Flasm](http://www.nowrap.de/flasm.html).

Note: Only works for flash 8 or earlier unfortunately.

[SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/about.html) might give you some information as well about the SWF files. They seem to be much more recent.

Answer (score 5):

As someone constantly working with SWF file format and ActionScript 2 and 3 bytecode, I highly recommend [ASV](http://www.buraks.com/asv). Unlike other decompilers, it has been designed to look into SWF files, not just convert them to FLA.

Also, you will need to read the following documents:

[SWF File Format Specs v10](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf)

[AVM2 Overview](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/actionscript/articles/avm2overview.pdf)

Comment: These links are broken for me.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to give the "just google it" answer, but it really is that simple if you [know what terms to use](http://www.google.com/search?q=flash+decompiler&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

Comment: He asked for a recommendation. Just because something ranks high on Google doesn't mean that it's the best option.

Comment: Today second result of google gets here. How can we still answer that in this century?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW: I have created an [ActionScript 3 (dis-)assembler](http://blog.thecybershadow.net/2010/05/05/announcing-rabcdasm/) (which allows you to assemble back modified code, even for obfuscated files). It is similar in functionality to flasm, however it targets the AVM (used in newer Flash versions), and works directly with the AS bytecode rather than entire SWF files. To edit the rest of the file, you could use a tool such as [SWiX](http://www.swixkit.com/).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to grabbing a Flash decompiler, you may want to read the [SWF File Format Specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/) docs.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [Trillix's Flash decompiler](http://www.flash-decompiler.com). It does the job I want it to do. But it's paid software, I use a demo version over and over (I only use it like 10 times a year).

Answer (score 0):

[Sothink Flash Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/download.htm)  is also pretty decent, and rants pretty good on [CNET's](http://download.cnet.com/Sothink-SWF-Decompiler-Flash-Decompiler/3000-6676_4-10073491.html) list of downloaded decompilers.

Answer (score 0):

I've had lots of luck working with AVE Imperator at http://www.ave-imperator.com/

It has helped me even get working actionscript to go along with the elements inside. It has more than one method of decompiling too, so often you can tweak the way you're decompiling it to get what you need.

Comment: Are you by any chance affiliated with this product?

Comment: Not at all. I first bought this software back in about 2006, and I've used it since then. It's worked great for me most of the time. Not everything decompiles perfectly, but I've used it to learn a lot of action script from high profile flash sites over the years.