# Tampering Flash website communication

Tags: flash, actionscript, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I don't have an swf file (I can save it). I am trying to debug into a "pre-coded" legacy website. What i want to know is that how it is communicating with server and what params its sending.

I have tried TamperData on Firefox but it didn't help. I used **Fiddler** and i can see that it is downloading swf file and that swf file is being responsible for communication.

My question is, how can i debug/tamper the SWF file request? Give the situation where SWF is dynamic for each request, i can't save it without setting up cookies/and setting up a proper session.

What could be leads to work on this projecT?

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678702/reverse-engineering-flash) but its not gona help me that much.

P.S:
The web use some business logic implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Wireshark](http://Wireshark.org) to record the live TCP stream while the swf is running as normal.